# Load values in select2 multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using `select2` in place of search box.

Here i'm using to load countries values like this

```
$("#countries").select2({
    multiple: true,
    tags:["India", "Japan", "Australia","Singapore"],
    tokenSeparators: [","]
});
```

When i press save button, they are properly submitted to the server, now here the question is
when i want to modify the country field after saving to server, how i can load the saved values to the country field.

This is how i retrieve data from server

```
$.getJSON('/dataprovider?data=fetchCountriesForm', function(opts) {

    //the opts here contains the json values of the countries.

    //what code should be written here to load the values in $('#countries).select2();

    //user can add some more countries or can remove the previously added countries. 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just use this http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#event_ext_change link and use the trigger function to load the values

```
$.getJSON('/dataprovider?data=fetchCountriesForm', function(opts) {
        parent.parent.parent.showLoader();
        if (opts) {
            $("#countries").val(opts).trigger("change");
        }
```

This trick load the value in the select box.

Comment: I know this is old so forgive me but this doesn't seem to work with a 2 dimensional array? I can load values such as ('dog','cat','mouse') but not ('1': 'Dog', '2':'Cat', '3':'Mouse'). Were you able to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Please have a look a [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) under section `Loading Remote Data`.

You will find and example like:

```
$("#e6").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a movie",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { 
           // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
          url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json"
          // Other stuffs
          }
});
```

Also you can do like this:

```
$.getJSON('/dataprovider?data=fetchCountriesForm', function(opts){
    $("#countries").select2({
        data: opts
    });
})
```

Your `JSON` data must be in format like below:

```
[{id:0,text:'enhancement'},
 {id:1,text:'bug'},
 {id:2,text:'duplicate'},
 {id:3,text:'invalid'},
 {id:4,text:'wontfix'}
]
```

Comment: I believe that the data retrieved from the url is loaded into search box on a user event. Like user types input then value is retrieved and he selects the value. What i want here is to load all the values retrieved from json without any user event. @Kishor Subedi

Comment: Thanks @Kishor for the help, but i found more easier way to do this, i just used trigger function to load the values.